# How to remove tags from display in form?

Tags: 8

I have this form tempate

```
<div class="a">
    {{ form.card.a }}
</div>
<div class="a">
    {{ form.card.b }}
</div>
```

and I want to to frame it with  tag like this.

```
<a href="/card?id={{ form.card.card_link }}"> 
    <div class="a">
        {{ form.card.a }}
    </div>
    <div class="a">
        {{ form.card.b }}
    </div>
</a>
```

so I made

```
$form['card']['card_link'] = [
  '#type' => 'item',
  '#markup' => $this->getCardLink(), //returns integer
];
```

But it still doesn't show what it supposed to. 
It inserts `<div id="edit-card-link" class="some stuff">needed integer</div>` inside `href="<here>"`

How should I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The `item` element type is a form element, `Drupal\Core\Render\Element\Item`.

This means that it gets a form element wrapper by default.

Rather than rendering the `<a>` wrapper in the Twig template, you could include it in the render array, and add `form.card.a` and `form.card.b` as its children:

```
// In your form handler class

function buildForm($form, $form_state) {
  // ...

  $form['card_link'] = [
    '#type' => 'html_tag',
    '#tag' => 'a',
    '#attributes' => [
      'href' => '/card?id=' . $this->getCardLink()
    ],
  ];

  $form['card_link']['a'] = array_merge($form['card']['a'], [
    '#prefix' => '<div class="a">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
  ]);

  $form['card_link']['a'] = array_merge($form['card']['b'], [
    '#prefix' => '<div class="a">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
  ]);

  // ...
}
```

The template then simplifies to this:

```
{{ form.card_link }}
```

Comment: it passed the value but pops error then User error: "card_link" is an invalid render array key in Drupal\Core\Render\Element::children() (line 97 of core\lib\Drupal\Core\Render\Element.php).

Comment: Sorry about that. I forgot that the renderer won't accept plain values as elements. I've rewritten the answer to build a render array which replaces the markup in the Twig template.